# HTTP 1.1 request line

Tags: http, proxy

i build proxy server and it works great, however there are some sites which he cannot handle.
I tried to reduce the problem to its core and this is what i came up with:
My test case is:   http://bits.wikimedia.org/en.wikipedia.org/load.php
which is one of the http messages transfered in each wikipedia page.
So i tried to build a request for it and send it via a socket like this:

```
String request1 = 
    "GET http://bits.wikimedia.org/en.wikipedia.org/load.php HTTP/1.1" + 
    "\r\n" + 
    "Host: bits.wikimedia.org" + "\r\n" +
    "User-Agent: MyHttpProxy/example.java (http://stackoverflow.com/q/5924490/319266)" +
    "\r\n" + "\r\n";
```

However i got 404 return code - which was strange because this page does exist!
I made alot of trys and made a new request which was different only in the request line:

```
String request2 = 
     "GET /en.wikipedia.org/load.php HTTP/1.1" + 
     "\r\n" + 
     "Host: bits.wikimedia.org" + 
     "\r\n" +
     "User-Agent: MyHttpProxy/example.java (http://stackoverflow.com/q/5924490/319266)" + 
     "\r\n" + "\r\n";
```

and it worked! a good 200 was brought back with 
some unimportent content("/* No modules requested. Max made me put this here */")

Can anyone tell me what is the problem here?
i looked at the rfc and i couldnt make any reason of this...

[Here](http://www.2shared.com/file/xlKShtOX/example.html) is the source code for running this test and print the resuls:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would provide the full URL in the request line only if you're going via a proxy server. Direct requests to a web server need to follow the form as in `request2` in your example.

Looking at the source, you send requests to port 80, which almost 100% means they're not going through a proxy. My guess is that you need to send `request1` to port 8080 or whatever port your proxy is listening on.

As for the RFC, take a look at [section 5.1.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.2). Note that the absolute path is used with proxies, and relative path with origin servers.

Comment: Technically, the server is supposed to accept the absolute syntax as well, but many servers do not.

Comment: Hi! first of all thanks for the response. How can i tell if my request is going through a server? Assume i want to make a "transparent" proxy server, how can i tell if my request will go to a proxy or directly to the origin? e.g: 
"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IytNBm8WA1c" and the above. BTW: i dont have 15 points in stackoverflow hence i still cannot mark answers as useull(but it is!)

Comment: Hi. 
If you're writing a transparent proxy server, then indeed you can't distinguish at the client level - that's the whole point of transparency. In that case, most of my reply does not apply.
If you write a proxy yourself, then you should see in its logs whether it saw the request. Alternatively, you can do a traffic capture and see whether the peer IP is the proxy one or the origin server one.